# Finding $f^{(n)}(0)$ of $1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k^2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Maclaurin series for function $f$ is $1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2^2}+\frac{x^6}{3^2}+...=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k^2}$.

How to find $f^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hint:  For a generating function $f(x)$, the coefficient of $x^n$ in its expansion is $n!\,{f^{(n)}(0)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

Particularly, all the odd coefficients are $0$ and all the even coefficients are $1/k^2$ (except for $f(0)$), hence,

$$f^{(2n)}(0)=\frac{(2n)!}{n^2}$$

Comment: That's a "Hint?  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh... well... whoops XD